# To what extent is someone who does "powerlifting" a "powerlifter"?

Tags: strength, strength-training, powerlifting

I do work out for strength, but I am not a professional powerlifter. Does that mean I have the right to, and expect a respectable position so forth, to be coining/coined as a powerlifter if I just do powerlifting exercises?

Should I reach some standard in achievements within powerlifting, like one reaching a desired goal, or enter a competition, i.e. and then I'll be labeled as a "bonafide" powerlifter? I mean I do the exercises, but I do not compete as of now, and I'm not quite strong either.

But is someone who writes and has gotten paid for writing a writer, despite having no degree?

Many filmmakers write scripts and did not go to college, but are respected and coined as writers. I want to know at what degree I can be coined as powerlifter.

I mean I can consider myself anything I want, but I want other people to respect it as well, and take me seriously.

Answer (score 5):

Ain't nobody can tell you who you are, son. Powerliftin' is three things, you see? It's the squat, the deadlift--yep, just picking it up off the floor--and the bench. Right there, that's powerliftin', ayup. You squat? Deadlift? Bench? Yeah? All right then, yer a powerlifter if you want it. Hell, I'll give y'a pass on one o' the t'ree if you got yrself some kind of injury. Still a powerlifter.

Me? I squat and deadlift, no bench just 'cause I don't feel like it--oh, I suppose my shoulder complains, too, but I really just prefer dips--and I say "I powerlift" but not "I'm a powerlifter".